# radially averaged power spectrum of a binary image does not look like power law

Tags: matlab, computational-physics, fftw

It has been known that Fourier power spectrum somehow obeys power law therefore the slope of the spectrum can be used to calculate the fractal dimension of an image. Many people have used it for texture analysis.

I wanted to calculate the Fourier fractal dimension of a binary vessel image and have produced radially averaged power spectrum, using the matlab code here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6167-calculation-of-fractal-dimension-of-fractal-surfaces-using-fft

the spectrum I have plotted is like this,

[image]

However, I was told that this curve does not look like power law. I want to ask whether the comment is true and why, and is it because I'm using binary image rather than gray-scale?

I was also told that power law plot should be like a straight line so I further extended my experiments and added Gaussian noise to my binary image, like this.

[image]

the plot now much more like a power law so the problem is that I did it with binary image, but adding the Gaussian noise destroy the image and the results is not valid.

I want to keep the result I had before but is there anyway to explain my plot to be valid?

Thanks

Comment: I think that you can fit a power law function and see how good is the correlation.

Comment: Your question suggests that you don't really understand what a power-law behavior means (e.g., "I was told that this curve does not look like power law."), and what the steps you are doing to verify this with a picture imply. You will not likely get answers here that actually mean anything to you if you don't understand these questions. My suggestion would be to read up on *why* one would expect pictures to have this behavior (and why adding white noise would *destroy* this property!) and then explore the issue yourself with examples.